# vintage.js with Shadowbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox, vintagejs

I would like to use vintage.js with shadowbox.js !

```
<a rel="shadowbox" href="large.jpg"><img src="small.jpg" /></a>
```

and the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){Shadowbox.init({ onFinish: function () { $('img').vintage({noise: 20}); } }); });
```

Shadowbox works fine but not the vintage apply to the image !

```
$ is not a function
[Break On This Error]   
onFinish: function () { $('img').vintage({noise: 20}); }
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Shadowbox creates a copy of the **per link-element** when it's using any of it's players.

To use your **[vintageJS](https://github.com/rendro/vintageJS)** effects with the **Shadowbox img Player**, Shadowbox provides an **ID** named **sb-player** that you can use as the appropriate **selector** for any of it's players.

Change **$('img')** to **$('#sb-player')** to then allow your HTML5 FX to be applied to the image in the opened Shadowbox.